# Underscore in integer input causes error in java

Tags: java

As is specified in the [Java Standard Editions docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/underscores-literals.html), any number of underscore characters (`_`) can appear anywhere between digits in a numerical literal, like so:- `int number = 100_000;`.

Out of curiosity, I tried inputting an underscore separated value (`100_000`) to an input that is expecting an integer. The code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int basicAmount = sc.nextInt();
    }
}
```

This resulted in a generic error message.

So my questions are:

1. Why does this happen? Why am I not allowed to input numeric values containing underscores?
2. Is there a way to allow users to input numeric values *with* underscores?

Comment: Keep in mind the specification is talking about integer literals in your source code, not about the `java.util.Scanner` class.

Comment: Can you share the error message?

Comment: As specified, underscores may appear **as literals**, i.e. when you write code: `int i = 1_000_000;`. Getting user input is something completely different and you're restricted to what the `Scanner` class recognizes as `int` values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The docs you quoted is about Java Source Code. It is saying that things like this are possible:

```
int i = 123_456_789; // same as int i = 123456789;
```

The text that `Scanner` reads is not Java source code.

The relevant documentation you should read in this case is [`Scanner.nextInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()), which will bring you to its acceptable format specified [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#Integer-regex). It is clear that `Scanner.nextInt` does not accept numbers with underscores.

One simple way to read numbers with underscores in them is to just read a token, and remove all the underscores in it:

```
int input = Integer.parseInt(sc.next().replaceAll("_", ""));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! But I was wondering, couldn't the team behind  the `Scanner` class add a functionality to allow numeric values separated by delimiters (which can be switched on or off with a flag parameter)? Something like this:- `sc.nextInt(10, true)` (the ten being the radix value, and an additional argument (for eg. with a parameter name of `allowDelimiter`) acting like a flag). What are its pros and cons?

Comment: @AlveMonke I don’t think there is a separate “team” behind every class… I personally don’t see why this is a useful method for `Scanner` to have. It’s not common that you’d have to scan Java source code, and when you do, you would use a proper Java lexer anyway. If you are proposing this as a feature to the standard library designers, you’d have to give very good justifications as to why they should use their limited time to work on your feature, rather than <insert more important feature here>.

Comment: @AlveMonke see also this [Eric Lippert’s answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/293819/5133585) about asking “why doesn’t this language have this feature”. The bottom line is, these are not really answerable.